# Change logo destination URL for only one page

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

How do you change the logo to link to the home URL for all pages except one? I want one page to link to another page when the logo is clicked.

Here is the PHP code for the logo:

```
<div class="section-boxed section-header">
<?php do_action('pexeto_before_header'); ?>
<div id="logo-container">
    <?php 
        $logo_image = pexeto_option('retina_logo_image') ? pexeto_option('retina_logo_image') : pexeto_option('logo_image');
        if(empty($logo_image)){
            $logo_image=get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo@2x.png';
        }
     ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo_image; ?>" alt="<?php esc_attr(bloginfo('name')); ?>" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a second section of PHP - with a slightly different DIV ID that is called when that paticular page is loaded, rather than this one which is called on all the other pages,

Copy, paste, change DIV ID `<div id="logo-container2">`, change link address.

In HTML - on the single page that takes them elsewhere - call

```
<div id="logo-container2">
```

Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to use the `get_permalink` method to check which page you are on, and use an `if` statement to tell it what the `href` should be.

```
<a href="<?= (get_permalink() == '/my-page') ?  esc_url(home_url('/go-to-page')) : esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>">
```

Haven't tested this, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use template_tag `is_page` as condition

```
   <div class="section-boxed section-header">
        <?php do_action('pexeto_before_header'); ?>
        <div id="logo-container">
            <?php 
                $logo_image = pexeto_option('retina_logo_image') ? pexeto_option('retina_logo_image') : pexeto_option('logo_image');
                if(empty($logo_image)){
                    $logo_image=get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo@2x.png';


 }
    // Default logo url to home
$logo_url =  esc_url(home_url('/');
// if is page about or id 5 anything inside is_page()
if(is_page('about') $logo_url =  esc_url(home_url('about');  

         ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $logo_url; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo_image; ?>" alt="<?php esc_attr(bloginfo('name')); ?>" /></a>
        </div>
```